# NextJS with "openai api" got 401 error at endpoint createChatCompletion() but 200 ok at createCompletion()

Tags: next.js, openai-api, nextjs-api-router

#### In short

NextJS api router [failed](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/blob/bookmark/openai-api-vs-nextjs-createChatCompletion-401error/demo1_w__nextjs_app/nextjs_app/pages/api/generate_createChatCompletion.js?ref_type=heads#L11) to call openai api endpoint `createChatCompletion()` while pure Node.js code can [succeed](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/blob/bookmark/openai-api-vs-purenodejs-createChatCompletion-succeeded/demo0_w__nodejs_app/nodejs_app/try_openai_gpt_api/try1_createChatCompletion.js?ref_type=heads).

#### Detail

I use NextJS 's `api router` as coded [here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/tree/bookmark/openai-api-vs-nextjs-createChatCompletion-401error/demo1_w__nextjs_app/nextjs_app?ref_type=heads) to call "openai api" endpoints using Node.js package [openai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai)

I got 401 at calling endpoint createChatCompletion() [view code](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/blob/bookmark/openai-api-vs-nextjs-createChatCompletion-401error/demo1_w__nextjs_app/nextjs_app/pages/index.js?ref_type=heads#L14) - though succeeded 200 with createCompletion() [view code](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/blob/bookmark/openai-api-vs-nextjs-createChatCompletion-401error/demo1_w__nextjs_app/nextjs_app/pages/index.js?ref_type=heads#L33)

[image]

I double check with pure Node.js code, and can [succeed](https://gitlab.com/namgivu_fullstack/ai_gpt/gpt_start_202308_nodejs/-/blob/bookmark/openai-api-vs-purenodejs-createChatCompletion-succeeded/demo0_w__nodejs_app/nodejs_app/try_openai_gpt_api/try1_createChatCompletion.js?ref_type=heads) calling `createChatCompletion()`, strange...

What am I missing?

p.s.

My search in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nextjs+%22openai+api%22+get+401+at+calling+createChatCompletion+though+succeed+200+with+createCompletion) and [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=nextjs+%22openai+api%22+get+401+at+calling+createChatCompletion+though+succeed+200+with+createCompletion&oq=nextjs+%22openai+api%22+get+401+at+calling+createChatCompletion+though+succeed+200+with+createCompletion&aqs=chrome..69i57.53139j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) result with no helpful found

Comment: Error seems to be in your application. Use
`try{//api call 
  ...
     }
     catch(error){
                       console.error("Error is :", error);
                       }` approach to identify the bug.

Comment: 401 code is unauthorized request. maybe you did not set the env variables correctly

Comment: @Yilmaz Nah, I use same code same env apikey, it works in pure nodejs code

Comment: did you `console.log` it

Comment: @Yilmaz alot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, nextjs define env in `next.config.js`

Sample

```
  // ... other nextjs config
  env: {
    APIAPP_HOST: 'http://yourapihost', 
    // ...
  }
```